# Weighted Kaplan-Meier Curve Log Rank Test

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

I need to compare two weighted KM curves created by using the `svykm` function from the `survey` package. I am unable to find any resources on how compare the two curves and want to know if there is anyway to do it. The survival package has the `survdiff` function but it does not account for weight.

Comment: I don't know of any R function to does that, but if you're willing to write your own code, this papers might be useful to you: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16189810 and http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19199275

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [svylogrank](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/functions/svylogrank) function from the [survey](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) package.